# Mongo aggregation with conditional date aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to mongo and am trying to get a sum of the total amount from my mongo db collection named "transactions" where "paid" is true and "creationDate" is in the month of September 2014, grouped by day.

In Postgres, I can write this as:

```
select to_char("creationDate", 'YYYY-MM') as "Month", sum(totalamount)
from transactions
where "creationDate" >= '2014-09-01'
and paid is true
group by "Month"
```

However, I'm not sure how to add the conditions for creationDate and paid in Mongo. I read up on conditional aggregations, but I'm not sure how to get it to work for the day and month of date, as well as for logical conditions.

Sample data:

```
{ "totalamount" : 10, "creationDate" : ISODate("2014-09-01T01:00:58.909Z"), "paid" : true}
{ "totalamount" : 30, "creationDate" : ISODate("2014-09-01T03:00:58.909Z"), "paid" : true}
{ "totalamount" : 20, "creationDate" : ISODate("2014-09-02T01:00:58.909Z"), "paid" : true}
```

This is what I tried:

```
db.transactions.aggregate( 
[ 
    { 
        $group: 
            {
                _id:  {
                    day: { $dayOfMonth: "$creationDate"}, 
                    month: 
                        {
                            $cond: [{ $gte: [$month: "$creationDate", 9]},9,0]                                
                        }, 
                    year: 
                        {
                            $cond: [{ $gte: [$year: "$creationDate", 2014]},2014,0]                                
                        }, 

                    },
                collected: {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond: [
                            {"$paid":"true"}, "$totalamount",0]
                    } 
                }
            }
    } 
]
)
```

However, I'm getting `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"`

Any insights into this would be extremely helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems in there so a bit beyond a comment. Mostly you were not enclosing several date operators with `{}` and as such producing invalid JSON inside an array. It helps if you change your indentation style as well to make it easier to spot formatting problems.

I also personally prefer to stick to fully strict JSON notation, it parses well with other languages and is easier to ["lint"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)), which is something you should look at to avoid coding syntax errors in the future:

```js
db.transactions.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$creationDate" }, 
            "month": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$gte": [ {"$month": "$creationDate"}, 9 ] },
                    9,
                    0 
                ]                                
            }, 
            "year": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$gte": [ { "$year": "$creationDate" }, 2014] },
                    2014,
                    0
                ]                                
            }
        }, 
        "collected": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$paid", "true" ] }, 
                    "$totalamount",
                    0
                ]
            } 
        }
    }}
])
```

Also the logical check with [**`$eq`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) was missing from that `$sum` at the end. Make your you actually mean the "string" value of "true" and not `true` as a plain boolean in this case as well.